# Is it possible to Unregister a BroadCast Lister

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver registered in the manifest for 5 different events.

For simplicity, let's say events are named A,B,C,D and E.

After receiving event B, i want to unregister the receiver to stop listening for event E. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Call `unregisterReceiver()` on the `BroadcastReceiver` you registered via `registerReceiver()`, then re-register it with the revised `IntentFilter`.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via the manifest, not via `registerReceiver()`, you can disable an entire `BroadcastReceiver` component via the `PackageManager`. However, I know of no way to disable an individual intent filter, so you may need to move the E logic into a separate `BroadcastReceiver`, so you can enable and disable it independently of others.